# PyCharm can't find Keras

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, keras, python-packaging

I'm trying to add Keras module into PyCharm. Keras is installed into `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-1.0.8-py2.7.egg`.

PyCharm interpreter settings looks like that:

[image: Interpreter setting]

Last two paths are just attempts to make it work.
This is definitely PyCharm configuration problem because keras is imported from interpreter without any problems.

Comment: Do you have more than one python installation? PyCharm might be looking at the wrong folders: go to `File > Settings > Project: ... > Project Interpreter` and make sure you're referencing the right one. Then `Run > Edit Configurations` and select the same python which you just set to be the project's default.

Comment: Check your Interpreter settings where you can add keras by your own.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the version of python you are utilizing is matched with the python version the Keras uses.

- Check your default python version by running this command in your cmd or terminal:  `python --version`
- Check your python version in PyCharm Interpreter by `File > Settings > Project: ... > Project Interpreter`.
- Match the version you utilize in PyCharm with the version you utilize in keras.

Answer (score 0):

In your system terminal, run command `which python`, it will give you the interpreter you are using in your system. it should be the same one you are using in pycharm.

Comment: Does this add anything new to the existing answer?

Comment: `which python` gives you the path of the interpreter you are using in your terminal